# how do i combine 2 tables and order it

Tags: sql, laravel-5

so i have 2 tables :

StockIn :

```
id   quantity   date        status_id
1    10         2017-05-01  1
2    20         2017-05-04  1
3    30         2017-05-06  1
```

StockTrf :

```
id   quantity   date        status_id
1    11         2017-05-02  1
2    21         2017-05-03  1
3    31         2017-05-05  1
```

i want to combine these 2 table into 1 table that ordered by date like:

```
id   quantity   date        status_id
1    10         2017-05-01  1
1    11         2017-05-02  1
2    21         2017-05-03  1
2    20         2017-05-04  1
3    31         2017-05-05  1
3    30         2017-05-06  1
```

i have no idea how to combine it.. can someone help me? thank you!
i am using laravel 5.2 btw, so if you know a better way to combine it with laravel syntax, i would appreciate it..

EDIT: i need to join this table to `statuses` table so i can get status name `Active` or `in-Active`. so how do i join `union` and `join` in laravel?

Statuses :

```
id   name
1    Active
2    In-Active
```

Comment: In SQL you would use `UNION ALL` with `ORDER BY id, date`.

Comment: Please show the table definitions for all three tables involved.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i edited it

Comment: @DennyRustandi I updated my answer, it may not work.  Try it and let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick review of the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#unions) would reveal how to do a simple `UNION`:

```
$first = DB::table('StockIn');

$second = DB::table('StockTrf')
        ->unionAll($first)
        ->join('statuses', 'StockTrf.status_id', '=', 'statuses.id')
        ->orderBy('date', 'asc')
        ->get();
```

This corresponds to the following raw `UNION` query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM StockIn
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM StockTrf
) t1
INNER JOIN statuses t2
    ON t1.status_id = t2.id
ORDER BY t1.date ASC
```

Comment: I think your get() and orderBy() got interchanged.

Comment: thank! btw i need to join this table to my `statuses` table so the output will show status name `Active` or `in-Active`. i know it will require `join`. but how can i combine it with `union` code?

Comment: No, I won't update my answer because your question mentioned nothing about a join.  You should either edit your question or open a new one.  Stack Overflow is not an ongoing forum where you keep asking new questions.  Ask one question, and then move on.

Comment: oh okay.. sorry i am new to stackoverflow

Comment: it didnt show `stockTrf` table output, but i changed it to `leftJoin` and it works.. thanks mate!!

Comment: oops.. my bad! your code works with`join`. it's just me mistaken to change the table's name because my real table's name not `statuses` and i just copy paste your code.. haha..

Answer (score 0):

Use UNION ALL Statement :

```
 SELECT *
 FROM 
 (
   SELECT id ,  quantity ,  date   ,     status       
   FROM StockIn
   UNION  ALL
   SELECT id ,  quantity ,  date   ,     status       
   FROM StockTrf 
 ) A
 ORDER BY quantity
```

Comment: This is a Laravel question.

Comment: Also, you don't need to wrap with a subquery, just tag `ORDER BY quantity` to the end of the `UNION` and it should apply to the entire query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen,Thanks for suggesstion,